# Best Practice: Loading component Styles & Scripts in J4

Tags: javascript, joomla-4.x, style

What is the best practice for loading styles and scripts?

Option 1:

```
HTMLHelper::stylesheet(Uri::base().'media/com_mycomponent/css/mycomponent.css');
```

Option 2:

```
$wa = Factory::getApplication()->getDocument()->getWebAssetManager();
$wa->registerAndUseStyle('mycomponentCore', 'com_mycomponent/mycomponent.css');
$wa->registerAndUseStyle('mycomponentList', 'com_mycomponent/list.css');
```

I've used both and they seem to work ok but what is the best bearing in mind the future into J5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both have pros and cons.

Web Asset Manager is great if your loading an asset that depends on another one. For example:

- some jQuery plugin
- that depends on jQuery

Your json file can set jQuery as a dependency, meaning you don't need to manually import it.

If you're loading a single file that has no dependencies, then the Web Asset Manager has a lot of unecessary overhead and you're probably best off using `HTMLHelper`

When it comes to Javascript, I never use the Web Asset Manager. If I need to import a dependency, I use JS [module imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

To answer your question, it really depends on the number of assets you're trying to import, which assets you need, how many views/layouts you have, etc.

Comment: Thanks very much for this feedback, much appreciated.  I tend to only use one file with no dependancies at all, so I'll keep using the HTMLHelper I think.  Cheers.